# Passing Data between Two Pages Without Navigating to it

Tags: flutter, flutter-navigation

I'm trying to pass data to a new flutter page, except I do not want to navigate to the view where the information is being sent when I click the blue button.
I'm using this code below, but on the web, it is weird to have an android-like transition.

```
 Navigator.push(
   context, 
   MaterialPageRoute(
   builder: (context) => ViewUserOutput(loadData: true)
   )
);
```

[image]

I want to send the data directly to the yellow portion without having it display fullscreen like this:

[image]

Thanks

Comment: you can use any statemanagment for flutter

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The best practice is to use the [provider](https://pub.dev/packages/provider) package available at the: https://pub.dev/. Here is an example of a simple counter app using the [provider](https://pub.dev/packages/provider) package:

***main.dart:***

```dart
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:provider/provider.dart';
import 'views/home_screen.dart';
import 'provider/counter_provider.dart';


void main() => runApp(MyApp());

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MultiProvider(
      providers: [
        ChangeNotifierProvider(
          create: (_) => Counter(),
        ),
      ],
      child: MaterialApp(
        title: 'Flutter Demo',
        debugShowCheckedModeBanner: false,
        theme: ThemeData(primarySwatch: Colors.blue),
        home: const MyHomePage(),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

***home_screen.dart:***

```dart
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:provider/provider.dart';
import '../provider/counter_provider.dart';

class MyHomePage extends StatelessWidget {
  const MyHomePage({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      backgroundColor: Colors.deepPurple[100],
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: const Text('Provider'),
      ),
      body: Center(
        child: Column(
          mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.min,
          mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
          children: const [
            Count(),
          ],
        ),
      ),
      floatingActionButton: Row(
        mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.end,
        children: [
          FloatingActionButton(
            onPressed: () {
              context.read<Counter>().decrement();
            },
            tooltip: 'Decrement',
            child: const Icon(Icons.remove),
          ),
          const SizedBox(width: 10.0),
          FloatingActionButton(
            onPressed: () {
              context.read<Counter>().restart();
            },
            tooltip: 'Restart',
            child: const Icon(Icons.restart_alt),
          ),
          const SizedBox(width: 10.0),
          FloatingActionButton(
            onPressed: () {
              context.read<Counter>().increment();
            },
            tooltip: 'Increment',
            child: const Icon(Icons.add),
          ),
        ],
      ),
    );
  }
}

/// As we have [context.watch] inside of our widget,
/// it will rebuild the entire widget.
/// Therefore we can create a standalone widget like the one below.
class Count extends StatelessWidget {
  const Count({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Text(
      '${context.watch<Counter>().count}',
      style: const TextStyle(fontSize: 40),
    );
  }
}
```

***counter_provider.dart***

```dart
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

class Counter with ChangeNotifier {
  int _count = 0;

  int get count => _count;

  void increment() {
    _count++;
    notifyListeners();
  }

  void restart() {
    _count = 0;
    notifyListeners();
  }

  void decrement() {
    _count--;
    notifyListeners();
  }
}
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you, I will try it out and see if it works before I accept tmrw

Comment: I forgot to mention that once I click the blue button, it's going to call an async function. Does this approach work with future builders?

Comment: Yes @KelvinJou , it works fine with FutureBuilder. Sample code:

FutureBuilder(
  future: Provider.of<T>(context,listen: false),
  builder: (context, snapshot) {return .....
     }
  );